# Allocating and using aligned double-precision arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am not very used to C and what I am trying to do seems a bit
complicated.

I would like to create two or more double-precision arrays 
that are 4096 bytes aligned. Here is what I tried and the 
various responses I get:

```
double *pp[2];

// Here  gcc warns about "cast to pointer from integer of different size"
    pp[0]=(double *)aligned_alloc(4096, 10*4096*sizeof(double) );

   *(pp[0]+1) = 55.55;  // This compiles but segfaults

// or

   *pp[0][1] = 55.55; //  This gives compilation error.
```

Has anyone any suggestions about doing this right?

### Thank you.

PS: is there a way of doing the same in fortran?

Comment: Assuming you have a version of gcc that supports C11, you need to include stdlib.h

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: adding -std=c11 did the trick. it now seems to be running ok. thanks again.

Comment: `*(pp[0]+1)` can be written as just `pp[0][1]` (with no `*` operator needed). However, you need to provide a _complete, verifiable_ example - an [MCVE].

Comment: i am testing all this in a prog of  few lines before i use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Add the necessary header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Then, the usage for the first array should be:

```
double *pp[2];
pp[0] = aligned_alloc(...);
pp[0][0] = 55.55;
pp[0][1] = 100;
```

Remember that `a[0]` is the same as `*(a + 0)`, you don't need the asterisk *and* the brackets.

Comment: `aligned_alloc()` is standard C:  "7.22.3.1 The `aligned_alloc` function"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Ooh, look! It's C11. I really am not up to speed there yet. Thanks for the clarification!